# Set global cultureinfo for decimal values

Tags: xamarin.forms, decimal, globalization, cultureinfo, culture

How to set CultureInfo globally for all decimal values.

Take one decimal value like

> 15.00

we may use 
`DecimalValue.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))`

so that it will convert for that culture and output is

> €15.00

But the question is am I able to **Set the culture info for all decimal values** that are going to display in the project?

Comment: You might consider implementing a custom value converter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) and dealing with the issue at the presentation, e.g.:
<Span Text="{Binding Val, Converter={StaticResource ValToCurrency}}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your better approach is too declare a converter for Decimal values, and use it wherever you need to display the values.

First you write your converter:

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return "0";
            decimal decimalValue = (decimal)value;
            return decimalValue.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

then, in your `App.xaml.cs`, inside `ResourceDictionary` you declare it to use it in your application

Now, in your pages, wherever you bind decimal values, you can use it like this:

```
   <Label Text="{Binding YourDecimalValue, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"/>
```